# Request URL from React (Vite) Front-End to Express.js Back-End includes page path and results 404 Not Found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, axios, vite

I created an Express.js Back-End that runs on port 4000. Also React (Vite) app runs on port 5173. I try to make some axios requests to my Back-End. Eventhough the URL looks wrong on DevTools when I make any request from my home page, it is still able to hit the Back-End and fetch the data (I can log the request on the Back-End console). But when I try to make a request from another page such as "127.0.0.1:5173/quiz", the request URL also includes "quiz". That's why I get 404.

So it shows "http://127.0.0.1:5173/quiz/api/quiz/:quizId"
But it needs to be "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/quiz/:quizId"

But like I said, it works when I make a request on home page:
"http://127.0.0.1:5173/api/quiz" - This works, and fetches the quiz list.

Btw, to solve CORS issues, I tried to add "proxy" on **package.json**, but it didn't work. Then I add some configurations on **vite.config.ts**, it worked, but like I said I kept seeing "http://127.0.0.1:5173" on Dev Tools Network tab instead of "http://127.0.0.1:4000".

Here's my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:4000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here's my request code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "./useAuthContext";
import { useQuizContext } from "./useQuizContext";
import { QuizType, Types as QuizActionTypes } from "../context/quiz/types";
import axios from "axios";

export const useQuiz = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const { state: authState } = useAuthContext();
  const { dispatch } = useQuizContext();

  const getQuiz = async (id: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const queryParams: string[] = [];

    // If it's a logged in user
    if (authState.user.token) {
      queryParams.push(`userId=${authState.user._id}`);
    }

    // If it's a participant who's done with the quiz
    if (localStorage.getItem("gifQuizUser")) {
      queryParams.push("participantCompleted=true");
    }

    const uri =
      queryParams.length > 0
        ? `api/quiz/${id}?${queryParams.join("&")}`
        : `api/quiz/${id}`;

    console.log(uri);

    // Fetch & Dispatch
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(uri);

      if (!response.data.error) {
        dispatch({
          type: QuizActionTypes.GetQuiz,
          payload: response.data,
        });

        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err.response.data.error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err.response.data.error);
      }
    }
  };

  return { isLoading, error, getQuizzes, getQuiz };
};
```

Thank you for your time.